# How to use mathscr font in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I set up MediaWiki in Ubuntu under Windows 10 WSL2 environment with the *math* extension up and running. Everything seems fine but I cannot get the latex format `\mathscr` working.

**Software setup**

Ubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) under Windows 10 (build 19043.1110) WSL2
Appache (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.3)
MySQL (mysql-8.0)
MediaWiki (1:1.31.7-1)

**Configuration**

I installed the *math* extension according to the [instruction](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Math) on the MediaWiki official page, by downloading the package associated with the latest stable [version](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ExtensionDistributor/Math) v1.36.

The following is the related modification in the LocalSettings.php file

```
wfLoadExtension( 'Math' );
// Set MathML as default rendering option
$wgDefaultUserOptions['math'] = 'mathml';
$wgMathFullRestbaseURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_';
$wgMathMathMLUrl = 'https://mathoid-beta.wmflabs.org/';
// Rendering options
$wgMathValidModes[] = array('png', 'source', 'mathml', 'latexml');
$wgMathDirectory = "/var/lib/mediawiki/images/math" ;
$wgMathPath = "/var/lib/mediawiki/images/math" ;
$wgTmpDirectory = "/var/lib/mediawiki/images/tmp" ;
$wgUploadPath = "/var/lib/mediawiki/images" ;
$wgUploadDirectory = "/var/lib/mediawiki/images";
$wgShowExceptionDetails = true ;
```

**Problem**

The Mediawiki works fine using latex highlights `<math></math>`, as it properly renders most latex equations. However, among others, it does not recognize the command `\mathscr`, such as `<math>\delta\mathscr{F}</math>`. Instead, it echoes

```
Failed to parse (unknown function "\mathscr"): {\displaystyle \delta\mathscr{F}}
```

I understand that `\mathscr` belongs to the latex package `mathrsfs`, so I got the impression that it is not included by default in the standard *math* extension? But the format does work on other public MediaWiki servers such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) (where the equations are rendered!) and [miraheze](https://miraheze.org/).

Comment: Have you asked in the MediaWiki support forum? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Project:Support_desk

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the comment! I post the question on the support forum you suggested, and realized that the very forum has the same problem I mentioned above, which does not occur for the Wikipedia or the miraheze sites.

Comment: Then they must have a custom setup that you will have to research.